# How to find the aspect ratio at which the movie was shot?

Tags: aspect-ratio

When looking for Baahubali 2015, I found an unplesant thing: the movie is around in several aspect ratios (16:9, 2.35), but obviously one is more cropped than the other. I had to download both movies and see which one is cropped.

Now with Baahubali 2017, how do I know which aspect ratio was the film shot at? I found [technical specs of the movie here](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4849438/technical?ref_=tt_spec_sm), but it doesn't say which of those aspect ratios is the native one, so naturally one of them will be more cropped than the other.

Answer (score 3):

The trouble with IMDB when used internationally is it shows information pertinent to where that specific user logged in from, so we're unlikely to see the exact same information you do.

I see two formats, 1.90:1 IMAX & 2.35:1. Neither is 16:9 and both would have to be cropped to 16.9, one vertically , the other horizontally [or post-boxed/letter-boxed]. Without knowing which of the cinema formats used the most of the frame, you'll never know which is the 'best' crop to 16:9. The original cinema format is almost never 16:9. If shot 35mm, most likely they cropped both out of the original film frame [3:2], at different aspect ratios. Neither is more 'correct' than the other.

When downloading/streaming, the metadata will only show the presentation format of the encapsulated movie, it cannot know whether it's been cropped, post-boxed or letter-boxed to fit into that format.

To be more specific on *"How to find the aspect ratio at which the movie was shot?"* You'll never know unless you find documentary evidence from the director etc. Even knowing what camera &/or film stock was used will not tell you exactly how the framing inside it was set up.

See: [How are some scenes for movies shot especially for iPhone viewing?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/115979/how-are-some-scenes-for-movies-shot-especially-for-iphone-viewing/115982#115982)

Comment: 1) I wasn't asking which is best crop to 16:9. I am not cropping anything. 2) if they shot at 3:2, then certainly one is better than the other (the aspect ratio closer to 1.5 will be certainly more complete). The key is to know the format the movie was shot at. Thanks anyway. Thanks for the link!

Comment: The movie was most probably shot at 3:2 as I already said. Both cinema versions were cropped from that. A streaming release will usually be letter-boxed from the 2.35:1… but it *might* not be [Dunkirk cropped the IMAX scenes & letter-boxed the rest for the streaming/DVD etc] Many 'catchup' stations will just crop the 2.35 down to 16:9 without a care. Movies are extremely rarely released on consumer formats at IMAX [4:3, Academy] ratio. There will be no publically available verion in the original 3:2 format.